# How can I make these text inputs active upon table row click in this existing script?

Tags: jquery, input, tablerow

I have this current script: http://jsfiddle.net/26eVE/9/

how can I make the other inactive input fields active when the user clicks the row?

EDIT: the text inputs must go back to their inactive state when the user clicks away from the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

I added:

```
active = $this.hasClass("active");

        if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input" && active) {
        return;   
        }
```

To allow input clicking without canceling the row

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/26eVE/13/

Comment: Hmmm... actually something I hadn't thought of came up. The user is obviously going to type in these newly activated inputs, but if they click on them, they will be clicking on the tr again, so the text inputs will go back to the inactive state. Is there any way to make this prevent from happening?

Comment: @menislici You can use an event handler on the text fields that calls [`event.stopPropogation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) to prevent the event from "bubbling up" to to the `<tr>` element.